# Zoom out in Octave / gnuplot

Tags: octave, gnuplot

I use Octave with gnuplot under Windows.

I can zoom in using the right mouse button. But how can I zoom out from the UI?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I found [this post on Nabble](http://old.nabble.com/zoom-td16353082.html). Pressing `p` takes you to the previous zoom level, `n` to the next level, and `u` unzooms. I pressed `h` in a gnuplot window outside of Octave and got this command list:

```
2x<B1>             print coordinates to clipboard using `clipboardformat`
                   (see keys '3', '4')
<B2>               annotate the graph using `mouseformat` (see keys '1', '2')
                   or draw labels if `set mouse labels is on`
<Ctrl-B2>          remove label close to pointer if `set mouse labels` is on
<B3>               mark zoom region (only for 2d-plots and maps).
<B1-Motion>        change view (rotation). Use <ctrl> to rotate the axes only.
<B2-Motion>        change view (scaling). Use <ctrl> to scale the axes only.
<Shift-B2-Motion>  vertical motion -- change xyplane

Space              raise gnuplot console window
q                  * close this plot window

a                  `builtin-autoscale` (set autoscale keepfix; replot)
b                  `builtin-toggle-border`
e                  `builtin-replot`
g                  `builtin-toggle-grid`
h                  `builtin-help`
l                  `builtin-toggle-log` y logscale for plots, z and cb for splots
L                  `builtin-nearest-log` toggle logscale of axis nearest cursor
m                  `builtin-toggle-mouse`
r                  `builtin-toggle-ruler`
1                  `builtin-decrement-mousemode`
2                  `builtin-increment-mousemode`
3                  `builtin-decrement-clipboardmode`
4                  `builtin-increment-clipboardmode`
5                  `builtin-toggle-polardistance`
6                  `builtin-toggle-verbose`
7                  `builtin-toggle-ratio`
n                  `builtin-zoom-next` go to next zoom in the zoom stack
p                  `builtin-zoom-previous` go to previous zoom in the zoom stack
u                  `builtin-unzoom`
Right              `builtin-rotate-right` only for splots; <shift> increases amount
Up                 `builtin-rotate-up` only for splots; <shift> increases amount
Left               `builtin-rotate-left` only for splots; <shift> increases amount
Down               `builtin-rotate-down` only for splots; <shift> increases amount
Escape             `builtin-cancel-zoom` cancel zoom region

                   * indicates this key is active from all plot windows
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Introduction-to-Plotting.html

I use    graphics_toolkit ("fltk")   to zoom plots for octave running on linux.